# Make Django admin object page show less?

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to have the item page in the django admin (ie, /admin/dictionary/word/153/change) show less, I am just unsure how to do this.

Given any random word can have say 10000 upvotes, it takes a while to actually make it to the page when it loads.  So don't want it to show the votes?

This is my admin.py and my models.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from diccionario.models import Palabra, Tag
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Tag

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class PalabraAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'nombre',
        'get_post_action',
        'definicion',
        'ejemplo',
        'gramatica',
        'get_sinonimos',
        'get_antonimos',
        'pais',
        'creado',
        'get_user_username',
        'aprobada',
        'anonimo'
    )
    list_filter = (
        'creado',
    )
    inlines = [TagInline]

    def get_sinonimos(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([item.nombre for item in obj.tag_set.filter(tag_type='Sinónimo')])

    def get_antonimos(self, obj):
        return ', '.join([item.nombre for item in obj.tag_set.filter(tag_type='Antónimo')])

    def get_user_username(self, obj):
        if obj.user:
            return obj.user.username if obj.user.username else obj.user.email

    def get_post_action(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/api/admin/aprobar/%s">Aprove</a>'
                         '<div style="margin: 5px 0"></div>'
                         '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/api/admin/borrar/%s">Borrar</a>'
                         '<div style="margin: 5px 0"></div>' % (
                             obj.id,
                             obj.id,

                         ))

    get_sinonimos.short_description = 'Sinónimos'
    get_antonimos.short_description = 'Antónimos'
    get_user_username.short_description = 'username'
    get_post_action.short_description = 'action'


admin.site.register(Palabra, PalabraAdmin)
```

And here is the models.py

```
import re

from django.db import models
from accounts.models import CustomUser


class IpAddress(models.Model):
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(unique=True)


class Palabra(models.Model):
    nombre = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    definicion = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    ejemplo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    anonimo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    aprobada = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    userUpVotes = models.ManyToManyField(IpAddress, blank=True, related_name='threadUpVotes')
    userDownVotes = models.ManyToManyField(IpAddress, blank=True, related_name='threadDownVotes')
    gramatica = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

Basically I want the userUpvotes and userDownvotes to now show on the object page in the admin of the word.  But not sure where I go about editing that template? Or is it in the admin.py?

Or take out the sections showing all the IpAddressObjects in this image
[image: issue]

Comment: *"I want the userUpvotes and userDownvotes to now show on the object page in the admin of the word"* is not so clear. Do you mean the IP address from each `IpAddressObjects`?

Comment: Have a look at [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude). You can add `userUpVotes` and `userDownVotes` to the exclude to not show them in the object page

Comment: @Damoiskii correct.  I want the IpAddressObjects that are showing in the userUpVotes and UserDownVotes to not show up when I am on the individual page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the commend from BrianDestura I was able to update my admin models with a exclude line added as such below

```
class PalabraAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'nombre',
        'aprobada',
        'anonimo',
        'get_post_action',
        'definicion',
        'ejemplo',
        'gramatica',
        'get_sinonimos',
        'get_antonimos',
        'pais',
        'creado',
        'get_user_username',
    )
    list_filter = (
        'creado',
    )
    inlines = [TagInline]

    exclude = ("userUpVotes", "userDownVotes")
```